# ExtJS 4: Ext.grid.Panel using Edit plugin calls "selectionchange" event twice when clicked if grid is a nested component

Tags: events, model-view-controller, extjs, grid, extjs4

Below is the event that is fired after a row is selected in an Ext.grid.Panel component.  I have a form with a grid inside of it as one of the items (child component).  The grid is being added using the xtype of the nested Ext.grid.Panel component.  For some reason, when I click a row in this nested grid component within the form, this event gets called twice.  It appears that it selects it, then the grid refreshes (it goes completely white/blank), and then it re-renders.  In a typical implementation of this exact same grid (not nested), this event only gets called once.

Two questions.  (1) How do I fix this in the short term?  (2) How would I troubleshoot this to find the cause?

**Event in controller:**

```
        'view-attribute-grid': {
            selectionchange: function (selModel, selected) {
                alert('selectionchange event called');
            }
        }
```

**Grid looks almost identical to this implementation, with a few minor changes:**

http://demo.rasc.ch/eds/extjs42/rowedit.html?theme=classic

## EDIT:

**Nesting:**

.. see `xtype: 'view-attribute-grid',` below ...

```
Ext.define('App.view.TestForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'view-test-form',

    requires: [
        'Ext.form.field.Text',
        'App.store.TestForm'
    ],
    initComponent: function () {
        this.addEvents('create');
        Ext.apply(this, {
            activeRecord: null,
            frame: true,
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            bodyPadding: 5,
            fieldDefaults: {
                anchor: '100%',
                labelAlign: 'right'
            },
            items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'ID',
                name: 'form_id',                
                allowBlank: false,
                disabled: true            
            }, {
                xtype: 'view-attribute-grid',
                itemId: Ext.id()
            }],

            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'bottom',
                ui: 'footer',
...
```

Comment: What exact version of extjs are you using down to 4.x.x

Comment: Explain the nesting part a bit. What's nested and where. A code sample would help.

Comment: I had same problem because I loading single controller twice: by fullname ('App.controller.some.contr') and by shortname ('some.contr')

Comment: @Reimius - I'm using version 4.2.1